# odbc library appears in link command

Tags: visual-c++, linker, odbc

As you can see in [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVhWh.jpg) the link command contains odbc library.

However, as you can see in [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXS7U.jpg) the library is nowhere to be found.

Where is the odbc.lib is coming from? Does anybody have an idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you open the linker inputs and show 'additional dependencies'? You might be inheriting a property sheet.

Comment: @OfekShilon, I believe the second link to imgur shows that screen already. Can you check?

Comment: No it doesn't. The shown text, additional dependencies, can match unshown inherited values. Either *open* the linker input field and inspect the evaluated value, or check the inherited pages for this project directly in the property manager.

Comment: @OfekShilon, I have MSVC 2010 Pro. The second screenshot does show "Linker->Input" fields and only "Additional dependencies" field shows the value. Can you clarify where do I check inherited pages? Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you don't *hover* above the linker input but open it?  (icon on the right)